# How to modify an xml attribute's value?

Tags: c#, xml

How can i modify the value of an attribute within an xml loaded using Loadxml()?

I'm trying to update the xml string stored in my db. For that, i used the following code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(project.ProjectData);
        XmlNodeList pNodes = doc.SelectNodes("project");
        foreach (XmlNode pNode in pNodes)
        {
            XmlAttribute lPDAttribute = pNode.Attributes["lastPubDate"];
            if (lPDAttribute != null)
            {
                string currentValue = lPDAttribute.Value;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentValue))
                {
                    lPDAttribute.Value = project.PublishDate.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

What should i do to save the updated attribute within my current xml? Please help.

Comment: Can you give us some more info about the scope? Are you creating the "project" node yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should add the below code line

```
project.ProjectData = doc.InnerXml
```

Answer (score 2):

you can store doc.InnerXml as a string in your db